# Is the Android "SDK Tools Only" Windows NSIS installer source code available anywhere on the Web?

Tags: android, installation, open-source, nsis

The Android [SDK Tools Only package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) includes the official Android emulator and lots of other useful things.

The source code of these tools is not so hard to find. But I'm looking for the source code for the *NSIS installer source code* which installs these tools on Windows machines.

Please note: I'm **not** looking for the [Android Studio installer source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/native/installer/win). Instead, I'm looking for the SDK Tools Only installer source code.

Is it even available anywhere on the Web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mentioned my request in an issue in the Android issue tracker. From what David Herman at Google wrote in reply, it looks like it's not available online. He wrote:

> I'm not sure what the plans for the SDK installer are moving forward - it may get deprecated by the current installer, especially as we roll more and more functionality of the SDK into Android Studio. At the very least, I'll look into it and see if porting it over to AOSP is trivial or not.
>
> For now, take a look at the BUNDLE_SDK define in the Android Studio installer. That tiny subset is likely similar to what the standalone SDK installer is doing anyway. (Basically, have a skeleton SDK somewhere on your computer and package it using NSIS).
>
> Note that there were a lot of bug fixes and polish changes that went into our current installer, and I think the SDK installer is a fork of the old installer well before any of those changes went in. You may find more success taking the current installer and cutting out all scripting code related to the DIR_SRC define (which points to the source directory for getting a clean copy of Android Studio). This may even be a valid approach we take, moving forward, to obsolete the existing SDK installer (e.g. add a new BUNDLE_STUDIO define)